# Creating simlink from yocto recipe

Tags: linux, yocto

I'm downloading libs from repository as name.so.version

```
SRC_URI_x86-64 = "fetch location"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}

    
    for file in ${WORKDIR}/location/lib*;do
        install -m 0644 $file ${D}${libdir}
    done
}
```

how can I in addition to coping the original files generate symbolic link filename.so to each of the files?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525426/yocto-create-a-symlink-in-an-image-recipe ?

Comment: I did but it shows how to do it on a known file name, I need a method which will strip out the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}

    # Install all libraries into the image folder
    for file in ${WORKDIR}/location/lib*; do
        install -m 0644 $file ${D}${libdir}
    done

    # Change directory to the image folder
    cd ${D}${libdir}
    for libfile in lib*; do
        # Strip the version
        stripped_libversion=$(echo $libfile | sed 's/\.so.*/.so/')
        ln -sf $libfile $stripped_libversion
    done

    # Go back to working directory ${S} or ${WORKDIR}
    cd ${S}
}
```